# How to specify "default" target labels when running bazel test

Tags: bazel

We're considering migrating to Bazel from Make. To make the transition easier I would like to have `bazel test` (no flags / options) run the current directory's tests, if any.

So instead of `bazel test my_tests` `bazel test` would find the current directory's `BUILD` file, find any `*_test` rules and run those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do exactly as you said then you can use your own script.
When you run “bazel” it actually looks to see if there is a script named “bazel” under tools directory of the current workspace. So if you have an executable under “$workspace/tools/bazel” bazel will run that instead of the bazel binary itself.
This means you can write a script that checks if the only argument is “test” and if so calls “bazel-real test :all”
It can also check the exit code to see if there were no tests (it’s a specific error code) and return 0 instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `all` target pattern to match all targets in the current package: `bazel test :all`

You can read more about it here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#target-patterns

Note however that if there are no test targets in the current package, bazel will give an error: "ERROR: No test targets were found, yet testing was requested.". In this case bazel will give an exit code of 4: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#what-exit-code-will-i-get

Comment: The links to the user manual have changed:
[Specifying targets to build](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#specifying-targets-to-build) and [What exit code will I get](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#what-exit-code-will-i-get)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a alias called `bazel-test` to `bazel test :all`.